# Remove Write and Modify access for Authenticated user using powershell

Tags: powershell, acl

I have to remove the modify and write permission for the authenticated users.

[image]

I am trying to use the below code but it is not removing the permission.

```
$systemDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where {($_.Name -eq "H")}

foreach($driveLetter in $systemDrives) {
    # Get the existing permissions for the drive letter.
    $permissions = icacls $driveLetter.Root

    # Remove the modify and write permissions for the Authenticated Users group.
    $permissions.Remove("Authenticated Users:W")
    $permissions.Remove("Authenticated Users:M")

    # Set the new permissions for the drive letter.
    icacls $driveLetter.Root $permissions
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue here